# Detect position of first difference in 2 strings

Tags: javascript, string-matching

What is the cleanest way of finding the position of the first difference in any two strings in Javascript?

```
var a = 'in the';
var b = 'in he';
findFirstDiffPos(a, b); // 3

var c = 'in the beginning';
findFirstDiffPos(a, c); // 6
```

Comment: c.indexOf(a) else a foreach going over every character

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can simply iterate through your strings and check it character-by-character.

```js
document.body.innerHTML += findFirstDiffPos("in he", "in the") + "<br/>";
document.body.innerHTML += findFirstDiffPos("abcd", "abcde") + "<br/>";
document.body.innerHTML += findFirstDiffPos("zxc", "zxc");

function findFirstDiffPos(a, b)
{
   var shorterLength = Math.min(a.length, b.length);

   for (var i = 0; i < shorterLength; i++)
   {
       if (a[i] !== b[i]) return i;
   }

   if (a.length !== b.length) return shorterLength;

   return -1;
}
```

The output is **`3 4 -1`**:
**`3`**: because strings differ at position 3
**`4`**: string `abcd` is a prefix of `abcde`, but they are of different length. The 4-th *(0-based)* character does not exist in string `abcd`. You can change this logic in accordance with your requirements
**`-1`**:  strings are equal

**Update:** As @torazaburo mentioned in comments, the code can be even easier - just make a loop until the `Math.max()` of their length. It will work because `s[i]` for `i >= s.length` will return `undefined` and condition will result in `true`.

```js
document.body.innerHTML += findFirstDiffPos("in he", "in the") + "<br/>";
document.body.innerHTML += findFirstDiffPos("abcd", "abcde") + "<br/>";
document.body.innerHTML += findFirstDiffPos("zxc", "zxc");

function findFirstDiffPos(a, b)
{
  var longerLength = Math.max(a.length, b.length);
  for (var i = 0; i < longerLength; i++)
  {
     if (a[i] !== b[i]) return i;
  }

  return -1;
}
```

Comment: The last two lines can be `return a.length != b.length? shorterLength : -1;`.

Comment: You could tighten this up a bit by using `longerLength` instead of `shorterLength`. Then the next-to-last line could be omitted.

Comment: @torazaburo I tried to provide logical and easily understandable example. However, your approach sounds really lighter, I will add this to my answer.

Answer (score 19):

#### Looping

The looping approach could be written a bit more succinctly as

```
function findFirstDiffPos(a, b) {
  var i = 0;
  if (a === b) return -1;
  while (a[i] === b[i]) i++;
  return i;
}
```

According to [jsperf](http://jsperf.com/find-location-of-non-match-in-string), this alternative is an unsurprising 5-20 times faster than the other ones here.

#### `Array#findIndex`

Since we are trying to find the index at which a certain condition holds, this seems like a perfect application for `findIndex`:

```
function findFirstDiffPos(a, b) {
  if (a.length < b.length) [a, b] = [b, a];
  return [...a].findIndex((chr, i) => chr !== b[i]);
}
```

( We need the longer array to be the one we look up into, so we reverse the order if necessary. We use `[...a]` to convert the string into an array of characters.)

Disclaimer: This is an ES6 interface that you will have to polyfill on IE (but not Edge).

This alternative is a staggering 20 times slower than the straight loop.

#### Recursion

Just for fun, here is a recursive solution:

```
function findFirstDiffPos(a, b) {
  return function _iterate([headA, ...tailA], [headB, ...tailB], n) {
    return headA !== headB ? n : headA === undefined) ? -1 : _iterate(tailA, tailB, n+1);
  }(a.split(''), b.split(''), 0);
}
```

#### Regexp

Also in the "just for fun" category, a regexp solution. We will construct a regexp of the form `/^(a(b(c)?)?)?/` from one string and match it against the other one, and check the length of the match.

```
function make_regexp(str) {
  var result = '';
  for (var i = str.length-1; i >= 0; i--)
    result = '(' + str[i] + result + ')?';
  return '^' + result;
}

function findFirstDiffPos(a, b) {
  return a === b ? -1 : b.match(make_regexp(a))[0].length;
}
```

Even if we precompile the regexp, this is still five times slower than a plain old loop.

Comment: I like the *while* solution, probably fastest overall while remaining concise.

Answer (score 3):

The function can use some ES5 features:

```
function firstDiff(a, b) {
  var idx;

  // Short ciruit if strings are the same
  if (a == b) return -1;

  // Go until difference found
  a.split('').every(function (c, i) {
    idx = i;
    return c == b[i]; 
  });
  return idx;
}
```

This will automatically return at the end of the shortest string.

#### Edit

A bit of code golf leads to the following:

```
// Concise for loop
function firstDiff(a, b) {
  for (var i=0; i<a.length; i++)
    if (a[i] != b[i]) return i;
  return i<b.length? i : -1;
}
```

Or using ECMAScript 2015 *findIndex*:

```
function firstDiff(a, b) {
  var i = a.split('').findIndex(function(c, i) {return c != b[i]});
  return a == b? -1 : i == -1? a.length : i;
}
```

But perhaps readability suffers. What is the criterion for selection?

For loop version of  torazaburo's while loop effort (it's worthwhile using basic methods because they are usually much faster than iterators and not much more code, if any):

```
function findFirstDiffPos(a, b) {
  if (a === b) return -1;
  for (var i=0; a[i] == b[i]; i++) {}
  return i;
}
```

Comment: Which ECMAScript 2015 features does this use?

Comment: @torazaburo—oops! *every* came out in ES5… fixed.

Answer (score 0):

For fun, here's a one liner.  It's not particularly readable though

```
const findFirstDiffPos = (a, b) => [a, b].sort((a, b) => b.length - a.length).reduce((a, b) => [...a].findIndex((c, i) => c !== b[i]))
```