# find the index that breaks match between two strings

Tags: javascript, arrays

lets say I have 2 strings:

```
var a = "abcdef", b = "abcdefgh";
```

I want to find the first index that breaks the complete match without iterating over the two strings and comparing every character with loop.

In this example I want to get **6** since *g* is the character that breaks the full match

Comment: Will `a` always be a substring of `b`?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Detect position of first difference in 2 strings](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32858626/detect-position-of-first-difference-in-2-strings)

Comment: Why no iteration?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this - `var index = b.indexOf(a) + a.length`

```js
var a = "abcdef", b = "abcdefgh";
document.write(b.indexOf(a) + a.length);
```

Comment: Hi, Welcome to SO! Since there are multiple answers already and if you're adding a new answer then you should add why do you think this is better? A working demonstration, explanation of your answer (at a very least). Also good to know: [How do I write a good answer?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer)

Answer (score 3):

Using `reduce`:

```
const findIndex = (a, b) => {
    if (b.length > a.length)
        return a.length;

    a = Array.from(a);
    b = Array.from(b);

    const result = a.reduce((acc, cur, ind) => {
        if (cur != b[ind] && (typeof acc.ind == 'undefined')) {
            acc.ind = ind;
        }
        return acc;
    }, {});

    return result.ind;
}
```

An example:

```js
let a1 = "abcdef";
let b1 = "abcdefgh";

const findIndex = (a, b) => {
    if (b.length > a.length)
        return a.length;
        
    a = Array.from(a);
    b = Array.from(b);
    
    const result = a.reduce((acc, cur, ind) => {
        if (cur != b[ind] && (typeof acc.ind == 'undefined')) {
            acc.ind = ind;
        }
        return acc;
    }, {});

    return result.ind;
}

console.log(findIndex(a1, b1));
console.log(findIndex('aaa', ''));
console.log(findIndex('hey:)', 'hey!'));
```

In addition, version with `for` loop. Special thanks to @[Andreas](https://stackoverflow.com/users/402037/andreas) for the advice about how `if` statements can be avoided:

```
const findIndex = (a, b) => {
    for (let i = 0, l = Math.max(a.length, b.length); i < l; i++) {
        if (a[i] != b[i])
            return i;
     }
     return 'equal';
}
```

An example:

```js
let a = "abcdef";
let b = "abcdefgh";

const findIndex = (a, b) => {
    for (let i = 0, l = Math.max(a.length, b.length); i < l; i++) {
        if (a[i] != b[i])
            return i;
    }
    return 'equal';
}

console.log(findIndex(a, b));
console.log(findIndex('aaa', ''));
console.log(findIndex('hey:)', 'hey!'));
```

Comment: It's laudable that you added all those "corner cases" but `if (a[i] != b[i]) { return i }` would be enough. JavaScript won't throw an error when you try to access a non-existent index of a string, hence in the worst case it would be `if (undefined != ...)`.

Comment: But: _"without iterating over the 2 string and comparing every character with for."_

Comment: @Andreas thanks, I've updated answer

Comment: If you change your `for` header than you can also strip the second `if`: `for (let i = 0, l = Math.max(a.length, b.length); i < l; i++) { ... }`

Comment: ...This is still using a for loop exactly as the question says not to?

Comment: @Andreas thanks for your great comment. I've added it into answer.

Comment: @Light please, see my updated answer

Answer (score 2):

Well in this scenario try `a.lastIndexOf(b.charAt(b.length));`

Answer (score 1):

Here's a quicker solution without loops -

```js
var stringA = "abcdef",
  stringB = "abcdefgh",
  firstOccurrence = stringB.indexOf(stringA);

if (firstOccurrence === -1) {
  alert('Search string Not found');
} else {
  var stringALength = stringA.length;
  document.write(firstOccurrence + stringALength);
}
```